# How to remove every second occurrence of an element in a given nested list in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Briefly, for input:

```
?- remove_second(([1,[2,1,[2],[3,3,[[3]],1,[1]],1],2,1,2,1,3],R).
```

Output: `R=[1,[2,[],[3,[[3]],1,[]],1],2,1]`.

My attempt isn't functioning:

```
delete_second_occurrence(_, _, [], []):-!.
delete_second_occurrence(X, Z, [X|O], [X|L]):-Z==0,nested_memeber(X, O),
    delete_second_occurrence(X, 1, O, L).
delete_second_occurrence(X, Z, [X|O1], L):-Z==1, delete_second_occurrence(X, 0, O1, L).

nested_memeber(X, [X|O]):-!.
nested_memeber(X, [Y|O]):-not(is_list(Y)),!, nested_member(X, O).
nested_member(X, [Y|O]):-(!,nested_member(X, Y));(!,nested_member(X,O)).

is_list([]).
is_list([_|_]).
```

Comment: Is that the output you want is it what you are getting?

Comment: `is_list/1` is an ISO predicate; no need to define it yourself. Also, you have a typo, `nested_memeber` versus `nested_member`.

Comment: Clarify your question. You have a syntax error in your example input, you are missing one of your parameters, and your attempt contains misspellings.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want all the lists to be unique?Every nested list and outer lists must have unique elemts.This should work in that case:

```
 memberr(X,[X|_]):-
       !.

memberr(X,[_H|T]):-
   memberr(X,T).

lengthOfList(List,R):-
   lengthOfList(List,0,R).

lengthOfList([],L,L).

lengthOfList([_|Tail],Acc,R):-
    NewAcc is Acc + 1,
lengthOfList(Tail,NewAcc,R).    


remove_second([],[]).          

remove_second([H|T],R):-
         remove_second(H,T,R,[]).

remove_second(H,[],[H|[]],List):-
          integer(H),
          \+ memberr(H,List).

remove_second(H,[],[],List):-
          integer(H),
          memberr(H,List).



remove_second(Elem,[H2|Tail2],[Elem|R],List):-
     integer(Elem),
    (
       \+ memberr(Elem,List) ->
        remove_second(H2,Tail2,R,[Elem|List])
    ).


remove_second(Elem,[H2|Tail2],R,List):-
     integer(Elem),
    (
        memberr(Elem,List) ->
        remove_second(H2,Tail2,R,List)
    ).

remove_second(Elem,[H2|Tail],[P|R],List):-
     (
     \+ integer(Elem) ->
         lengthOfList(Elem,L),
         L > 0,
         remove_second(Elem,P),
         remove_second(H2,Tail,R,List)
      ).

remove_second(Elem,[H2|Tail],[[]|R],List):-
     (
     \+ integer(Elem) ->
         lengthOfList(Elem,L),
         L == 0,
         remove_second(H2,Tail,R,List)
      ).

    remove_second(Elem,[],[[]],_):-
     (
     \+ integer(Elem) ->
         lengthOfList(Elem,L),
         L == 0
      ).  

remove_second(Elem,[],[P],_):-
     (
     \+ integer(Elem) ->
         lengthOfList(Elem,L),
         L > 0,
         remove_second(Elem,P)
         ).
```

Not the most optimal code but it will solve the problem.

You get this output  `R = [1,[2,1,[2],[3,[[3]],1,[1]]],2,3]` with your input = `remove_second([1,[2,1,[2],[3,3,[[3]],1,[1]],1],2,1,2,1,3],R).`
 There are many predefined predicates which you can remove, like memberr to member and lengthOfList etc