# Prolog - sort sublists of a list

Tags: prolog

I want to sort the sublists of a list which contains integers eliminating the duplicates. Example:

```
[1, 2, [4, 1, 4], 3, 6, [7, 10, 1, 3, 9], 5, [1, 1, 1], 7]
=>>>
[1, 2, [1, 4], 3, 6, [1, 3, 7, 9, 10], 5, [1], 7].
```

I know that i have to work with functor s(but i didn't really get it).
Here is my code : (the (insert+sorting) function works in a simple list of integers,but don't work here. i'm getting red false everytime)

```
insert(E,[],[E]).
insert(E,[H|T],[H|L]):-
    E>H,
    insert(E,T,L).
insert(E,[H|T],[H|T]):-
    E=H,
    !.
insert(E,[H|T],[E|[H|T]]):-
    E<H,
    !.

sort([],[]).
sort([i(H)|T],L):-
    sort(T,L1),
    insert(i(H),L1,L).
```

Comment: Why not use the `sorted/2` predicate?

Comment: Hi,Willem.We didn't study predefined functions at course. Our teacher likes this kind of implementations -.-.

Comment: What is the `i` in `sort([i(H)|T],L)` supposed to do?

Comment: It is supposed to be a functor(a composed object). like : date(2,"Feb",1997)

Comment: You need to handle dfferent cases, if you see a red fasle instead of a result that means pattern matching failed at some point.There are 4-5 cases you need to handle to remove dupplicates from nested lists.

Comment: @LuaiGhunim How should look like? I said before that we learned something about composed objects,with that "i",but i don't know how to work with them properly. What could be your solution?

Comment: @EduardAdrian you are sorting a list of integers and trying to remove duplicates, i don't see any "composed object"?

Comment: @LuaiGhunim Ok,let's forget all the "composed object" thing. My program gets to the 3rd element which is a list. how should i make prolog to understand that  element is a list and he should sort it and then go to the next element?

Comment: your list contains integers and lists of integer, so you can simply say "integer(H) " which will return true if H is an integer otherwise it will fail and you can also say "\+ integer(H)" means if H is not a integer then it's a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a solution like this, it uses the the [sort/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sort/2) predicate to sort sublists:

```
sort_sublists([], []).
sort_sublists([X|Xs], List) :-
    (integer(X) ->
        List = [X | List1]
    ;
        sort(X, Sorted),
        List = [Sorted | List1]
    ),
    sort_sublists(Xs, List1).
```

Example call:

```
?- set_prolog_flag(answer_write_options,[max_depth(0)]).
true.

?- sort_sublists([1, 2, [4, 1, 4], 3, 6, [7, 10, 1, 3, 9], 5, [1, 1, 1], 7], X).
X = [1,2,[1,4],3,6,[1,3,7,9,10],5,[1],7].
```

Answer (score 0):

@Eduard Adrian it's hard to answer in comments, so first thing you need to do is to remove duplicates from the nested lists.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47046227/how-to-remove-every-second-occurrence-of-an-element-in-a-given-nested-list-in-pr) i tried that and you can see different cases that you need to handle. One example:(Head of your list can be a list but it's tail will be empty this happends if last element of your list is a list) in that case you need to define another predicate which will match your recursive call.

Once you have removed duplicates you can use simple sorting algorithm but you have to check if the head is a list then you sort innner list first and place it to the same place otherwise call sort predicate.

As you asked how check if an element [is_list](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=is_list/1) or [integer](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=integer/1), for that you can always use built-in because those predicates you can't write by yourself.